# how to deploy a reacjs application in linux?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

newbie in node and reactjs. I created a sample application with create-react-app. I ran npm run build to build the project and once successfully built saw following .
what does the static server mean here. I am planning to build a app, not just static web pages. will these steps to build and deploy work, if I copy the build folder to my development box and ran the following commands.

do i need to install any web server for it work in a linux dev box? how does the deployment work in nodejs/linux work, compared to like in microsoft box , you have to install IIS web server then deploy the website under it.

```
The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

  npm install -g serve
  serve -s build
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the developing phase you can use `npm start` to start a dev server that auto reloads on changes. (Pretty neat).

When you want to host your app you should use the `npm run build` command and deploy it as a static website. You can use a basic Apache Server for that. Your build folder should contain an index.html and various js files that will be loaded when a user requests your website.

Voilá you hosted your react app ;)